# How to make a div fadeout if a text box is empty in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here am sending contents of the textbox with class searcher using keyup event by ajax. I wanted not to send ajax request if the textbox with class searcher is empty and clear the content of a div with id sub_cont. but i couldn't do it.

anyone help with pointing out where am wrong

thanks

```
$(".searcher").keyup(function(){

        if($('.searcher').val == "")
        {
        $('#sub_cont').fadeOut(1500);
        }
        else{

        //show the loading bar
        showLoader();
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#content #sub_cont").load("main/search.php?val=" + $("#search").val(), hideLoader());
    }

    });
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML - how many other elements have the class `searcher` ?

Comment: Sorry, you are really hard to understand. I assume, that you want to `$("selector").fadeOut();` when a certain `$("input#selector")` is empty/the value is == ""?

Comment: Could you please mark David's answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// cache commonly used selectors (but not in a global scope, please).
var sub_cont = $("#sub_cont");
$(".searcher").keyup(function(){
    // check if the value of the input is empty or whitespace
    // you don't need to check the length of the string or even 
    // bother checking if it is `== ""` as an empty string already
    // evaluates to false.
    if(!$.trim(this.value)){
        // stop any existing animations before fading out
        // so we don't have ourselves a long queue of animations.
        sub_cont.stop().fadeOut(1500);
    }
    else{
        showLoader();
        // **Note: While `$.fn.load` is certainly the easiest way to do it,
        // other methods, such as $.fn.get are much more robust.**
        // (see my comments in the body of the answer for why)
        // Use the `data` parameter to make sure your values are encoded and
        // concatenated properly. This also allows for much more maintainable 
        // code
        sub_cont.load("main/search.php", {"val": this.value}, function(){
             hideLoader();
             sub_cont.stop().fadeIn(1500);
        });
    }
});
```

You should use `$.get` instead of `$.fn.load` here for several reasons:

1. This "autocomplete" function will be called every time a key is pressed. Using $.get you can cache the jXHR object and `abort()` the previous ajax request before sending a new one.
2. Errors happen. `load` gives you no escape hatch if there is an error whereas `get` does.
3. By implementing these suggestions yourself by reading the [jQuery docs on `$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) you'll learn a lot more about jQuery and javascript. :-p

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
if($('.searcher').val() == "")
```

Comment: You've got an extra period (`.`) between the `val` and the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.searcher').val` is not an existing property, you want to use the function `.val()`

Answer (score -1):

For checking if a `<input id="id" type="text" />` (works for textarea too if you change the selector) is empty:

```
if($('input#id').val().length > 0) {
    // is not empty
} else {
    // is empty
}
```

If you want to ignore simple whitespaces (trimming) do this:

```
// Main check here - I just added a .trim()
if($.trim($('input#id').val()).length > 0) {
    // is not empty
} else {
    // is empty
}
```

Applied on your code, we end up with something like this:

```
$(".searcher").keyup(function(){

    if($.trim(this.value).length > 0) {
        // is not empty
        showLoader();
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#content #sub_cont").load("main/search.php?val=" + $("#search").val(), hideLoader());
    } else {
        // is empty
        $('#sub_cont').fadeOut(1500);
    }

});
```

Many people use `if($('input#id').val().trim() == "")` instead of `if($('input#id').val().trim().length > 0)` but the second variant is faster because it just compares to integers which doesn't take as much time as comparing to strings,

Comment: Oh wow, please don't do this. Modern browsers already have `String.trim`. Also jQuery already [gives you a `trim` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Comment: You're right - my trim thingy was coded quick and dirty. I should check if there's already a trim() defined. But I dislike using jQuery, when it's unnecessary. I'll fix that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to utilize the heavily scrutinized and thoroughly tested functions provided by jQuery instead of your own broken and [much slower](http://jsperf.com/compare-trims#bs-results) version of the same? Also, you recommend `$(this).val()` when `this.value` will work in (probably) every browser and is *much* faster than its jQuery counterpart.

Comment: You taught me a lesson, David. Thank you ;)

Comment: Please use David's answer. It's better for several reasons.